# cakephp logic - other methods to get the same result

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.2

i've been trying to solve this problem for days. please assist or suggest another methods if possible. i am able to display the total score of the 10 lessons for every student in chrome, safari and firefox. however, i got this error "this page can't be displayed" in IE9/10.

I tired to debug and discovered that IE9/10 shows the above error when I use a for loop through the requestAction. having said that, i would require the requestAction to get the total score.

To get the total score i depend on the for each loop ( foreach ($customers as $customer) { ... } ) to get each $customer['Customer']['id'] and pass it to the requestAction and return back the score result.

QNS 1. Is there another way to achieve this result?

QNS 2. Can I do everything in the controller instead? If so, how?

**CONTROLLER**

```
function eachlesson($lessonid, $sessionkey, $customer_id) {

return $this->Score->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Score.test_bk_session_id' => $sessionkey, 'Customer.customers_types' => 'student', 'Score.lesson' => $lessonid, 'Score.customer_id' => $customer_id)));

}
```

**VIEW**

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($customers as $customer) { ?>
<tr>
   <td>
      <?php echo $customer['Customer']['customers_name']; ?>
   </td>
   <td>
   <?php 
   $customer_id = $customer['Customer']['id'];
   $sessionkey = $this->params['pass'][1];

   //LOOP THROUGH 10 TIMES TO GET LESSON 1 - 10 SCORES
   for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { 
       $lessonid = $i;
       $score = $this->requestAction('/scores/eachlesson/'.$lessonid."/".$sessionkey."/".$customer_id);


   //GETTING THE TOTAL SCORE FOR LESSON 1 TO 10
   (int)${'totaleachlesson'.$i} = $score['Score']['BI_pts'] + $score['Score']['FD_pts'] + $score['Score']['PO_pts']  + $score['Score']['WW_pts'] + $score['Score']['MG_pts'] + $score['Score']['FO_pts'];

   }

    //ADDING THE TOTAL SCORE OF THE 10 LESSONS
   $figureofcorrecttotal = $totaleachlesson1 + $totaleachlesson2 + $totaleachlesson3 + $totaleachlesson4 + $totaleachlesson5 + $totaleachlesson6 + $totaleachlesson7 + $totaleachlesson8 + $totaleachlesson9 + $totaleachlesson10;

   //DISPLAY THE TOTAL SCORE
   echo $figureofcorrecttotal;

   ?>
   </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

**HTML OUTPUT**

```
  <table class="tablesorter summary3pt2">
        <thead>
        <tr> 
                <th width="170" style="padding-right:5px;" class="empty">Name</th> 
                <th width="120" class="header">No of Correct</th> 

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                        <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Drew Parsons                </td>
            <td>
         2                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Natasha Francis                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Johanna Harmon                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Aubrey Mckenzie                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Edith Sims                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Brandy Ruiz                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Toni Marshall                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Cedric Nash                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Penny Maldonado                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Brandi Perry                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Conrad Hogan                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Travis Sparks                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Winifred Watson                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
            <td class="bold" align="right">
            Shannon Strickland                </td>
            <td>
         0                </td>
            </tr>
                        </tbody> 

        </table>
```

Comment: I suspect that there and error in the Html but I can't be sure unless you add some example `html` that is generated. However, retrieving the scores should really be directly retrieved from a model inside the controller. RequestAction is often bad for performance and causes a lot of overhead.

Comment: Yep, the server doesn't care what browser your running, so the error will be with the generated HTML. Post that.

Comment: hi guys. i've post the html output. i doubt there is error in the html. thaJeztah. you've suggested that i should retrieve the result from the model inside the controller? do you have any example i can follow since i require the requestAction to get the score result.

Answer (score 1):

First off, why do you "**HAVE**" to use requestAction?  You're not following cake conventions at all..  You need to take a minute and go read the documentation... Imo, you want to associate the "Score" model with the "Customer" model and contain the two in one call.

```
<?php
// Customer model.

class Customer extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Customer';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Score' => array(
            'className' => 'Score',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
            'limit' => 10,
            'conditions' => array(
                '<conditions go here>'
            )
        )
    );
}

?>
```

---

```
<?php
// Score model.

class Score extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Score';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'className' => 'Customer',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id' // This assumes you have a customer_id field in the 'scores' table.
        )
    );
}

?>
```

Now the models are associated, if you haven't attached containable behavior to them you can do so in each model or in the main app_controller.php by adding:

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Now all you have to do is contain the Score model when performing finds on the Customer model and the 10 Scores will automatically be retrieved for you.

```
<?php
// customers_controller.php

class CustomersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Customers';

    function index() {
        // Contain the child method.
        $this->Customer->contain(array(
            'Score' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Score.test_bk_session_id' => $sessionkey,
                    'Score.lesson' => $lessonid
                )
            )
        ));
        $customers = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Customer.customers_types' => 'student'
            )
        ));
        // Now you have all your customers, AND their associated
        // scores. No more request action needed (never use that imo)
        $this->set('customers', $customers);

        // Your array should look like this:
        // $customers =
        //array(
        //    [0] => array(
        //        'Customer' => array(<CustomerArray>),
        //        'Score' => array(<ScoreArray>)
        //    ),
        //    [1] => ...
        //)
    }
}

?>
```

I wrote this pretty fast so please excuse any mistakes or wrong-assumptions.  Hope this helps your problem.

Comment: As far as the original "This page cannot be displayed." I would put money that IE is blocking all the requests, thinking it is spam.. Since who knows how many customers you have thats 10 HTTP requests PER customer...  Just 100 customers would give you 1000 requests per page load of about 1-2 seconds. So about 500 HTTP requests per second... VERY inefficient.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! i agree with what you said. i will try your codes to see if it works for me.

Comment: hey drew, i don't have a 'lesson' table. at the moment, a user enter a test, the lesson no. and the score will be store as a row in the 'score' table. what i trying to achieve is to get the together marks for the 10 lessons rows/records in the score table for each student.

Comment: Okay, so you just have a customers and a lessons table then?  You can remove the Lesson table and all references to it in the code I provided.  Do the same thing, contain the scores table with the customers table, then apply your conditions, and run the query. (I will edit my post to reflect these changes)